# SPARQL Query - can't resolve prefix

Tags: javascript, sparql, rdf

I have a web-based [ontology](http://kalenav.github.io/ontology.rdf) that I want to query with SPARQL. I'm using JavaScript, so I set up a query engine with Comunica and got it to work: the `select * where {?s ?p ?o}` query did return what I expected it to return. However, I'm having issues with resolving the prefix for my ontology. It just doesn't seem to work. The following query returns an empty array:

```
PREFIX lab2: <http://kalenav.github.io/ontology.rdf>

SELECT ?firearm
WHERE {
    ?firearm rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* lab2:Firearm .
}
```

While the following query returns the expected array of individuals:

```
SELECT ?firearm
WHERE {
    ?firearmClass rdfs:label "Firearm"@en .
    ?firearm rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* ?firearmClass .
}
```

I tried passing the following as the link for the prefix:

- https://kalenav.github.io/ontology.rdf
- https://kalenav.github.io/ontology
- https://kalenav.github.io/ontology.rdf#
- https://kalenav.github.io/ontology#
- absolute path to the local ontology
- relative path to the local ontology (yielded error)
- http://www.semanticweb.org/konst/ontologies/2023/1/lab2
- http://www.semanticweb.org/konst/ontologies/2023/1/lab2#

All of those (except for the relative path) yielded an empty array, which leads me to believe that the prefix is not being resolved correctly.

Comment: open your ontology in a text editor - what ever you did during creation, there is no class `lab2:Firearm .` nor any other meaningful property or class name. There are only random place holder names with random numbers, e.g. `http://www.semanticweb.org/konst/ontologies/2023/1/lab2#OWLClass_08a105e0_50a4_4d15_919e_acf7c8e3f1c0` or `http://www.semanticweb.org/konst/ontologies/2023/1/lab2#OWLObjectProperty_b1e2a058_391b_4d2b_87b2_c0d259d3dac3` - that looks more like the serialiazion of whatever you used is writing the object type and the object hash of whatever programming language you used

Comment: oh wow, this explains it... I tried using the 'hash' string of the Firearm class instead of the label in the query and it returned what I expected. could you please submit this as an answer so that I can close this question?
also, do you happen to know whether I can safely manually change this hash string to my desired string in the ontology file?

Comment: @akrick, from past experience, UninformedUser is too edgy to actually post answers, and prefers to only communicate in comments on this site. Feel free to copy-paste his comment into an answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by UninformedUser in the comments. The issue was that, for some reason, the class IRIs were assigned `OWLClass` and some hash string instead of their labels, which prevented me from accessing the desired class via `lab2:{label}` in SPARQL.